# Understand Mozilla Thunderbird folders in Ubuntu

Tags: directory, thunderbird, email

I want to delete all files which are in the "outgoing" and "drafts" folder of a certain email (IMAP) account in my Thunderbird. Obviously it will by located in the /home/username/.thunderbird folder. But where exactly?

The background of my question is the following: I accidentally put the wrong recipient in my email, a recipient which under no circumstances should read this mail. While sending I noticed this accident and quickly clicked "cancel" and went offline. In my webmail interface the mail was in the drafts folder but not in the sent folder. So I hope it has not been sent. But I am afraid that locally it is still hanging somewhere in an "outgoing" or "to be sent later" folder. So before opening Thunderbird again I would like to delete all such folders on my hard disk.

Therefore I have to know how these folders are called and where they are located.

Quick help appreciated. It is an urgent matter!! Thx!

My OS: Ubuntu 13.10

Here is how my ImapMail folder looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is located at

```
/home/user/.thunderbird/Profiles/user.default/ImapMail/Server_Name/
```

[image]

**Note**: Deleting these folders will delete all messages in them

I would recommend that you get a backup of the folders in question, before you delete anything.  You can use the add-on ImortExportTools.

[image]

Comment: Do I not have to go into the ImapMail folder instead of the Mail folder? It is an IMAP account ... Plus: Why do I also have to delete the sent folder?

Comment: That is correct.  I have updated that in the answer.  Sent is the outgoing mail.

Comment: I see you have changed it to Imap now. But why do I have to delete the sent folder? Does sent not contain the list of mails I have sent? I wouldn't like to destroy all of them!

Comment: I have added a screenshot how my Imap folder looks like!

Comment: What is the file secureimap.t-online.de.msf ... are you sure that the folders indicated by you are the only relevant ones The point is that if I look into those files I cannot interpret their content. It is just code ... Isn't it possible to find single files and their contents in the thunderbird folder somewhere?? So that I can find my specific mail somewhere? perhaps using the search function of Ubuntu? Problem is that I do not understand at all this file system of TBird and how it saves mails ... :-(

Comment: How many accounts do you have setup in Thunderbird?  Can you add a screenshot of the main TB window?

Comment: No I can't add a screenshot of TB because then I have to open it and perhaps it will send this damned message! I have three imap accounts ... don't ask me why it lists this t-online account 4 times! :-(

Comment: Disconnect the machine from the  network, and ope it that way.